# Setting Absolute Path with Subdomain

Tags: php

I'm trying to include "enable_submit_button_all_fields.js" into a page which is on a subdomain.  I'm including it like this

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . PUBLIC_ROOT_PATH . '/' . GLOBAL_DIR_PATH . '/js/phone_number_formatting.js"></script>';
```

Where `PUBLIC_ROOT_PATH` is `/home2/host_uername/public_html`and `GLOBAL_DIR_PATH` is `globals`.

The file definitely lives at `/home2/host_uername/public_html/globals/js/enable_submit_button_all_fields.js`, but I keep getting a 404 error that indicates it's trying to get the file from `http://subdomain.domain.com/home2/host_username/public_html/globals/js/enable_submit_button_all_fields.js`

Any ideas?

Comment: The JS file is accessed by the browser, which is not allowed to access the root of your server's filesystem. You need to send the path relative to the document root (probably `/globals/js/enable_submit_button_all_fields.js`)

Comment: Pretty close, I would like to add that the issue is not so much that JS "is not allowed access", but that it is executed on the client computer, which does not share the file system at all.